# using try_files for a route with static html files

Tags: reactjs, nginx, routes, url-rewriting, static

I have a React/Nginx application with static html files that are accesses follows:

NGINX config:

```
location /blog/fn1 {
   try_files $uri /static/html/blog/fn1.html;
}
```

another location block etc...

How can I make this work for any /blog/ with one location block?

So far I tried:

```
location /blog/blog1 {
   try_files $uri /static/html/blog/blog1.html;
}

location /blog/blog2 {
   try_files $uri /static/html/blog/blog2.html;
}
```

etc...

This works but is obviously ugly and completely unmanageable.
I couldn't find any documentation for this scenario.

Comment: You could reuse the `$uri` variable, for example: `try_files $uri /static/html$uri;`

Comment: try_files $uri /static/html$uri.html seems to do the trick thanks